# Adjust cell height with UIImageView on it

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an imageView on a `UITableViewCell`, and I want to set height of the cell / imageView to a different value compare what I set in prototype cell. I do not want to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, because I do not want to precalculate the height of the content. If **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** is set and at least on iOS 8 `heightForRowAtIndexPath` does not need to implement.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    let iv = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "img1")
    let cs = iv.constraints.first! as NSLayoutConstraint
    cs.constant = 100
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    return cell
}
```

Structure of the prototype:

[image][image]

Although the height of the cell in prototype is set to 44.0 px, but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I want to override this value with 100.0 px.

Comment: Just to check - you want your tableview cells to automatically resize themselves using Autolayout based on the size of the `UIImageView` at runtime?

Comment: I forget to **add the bottom constrain** of the image, that caused the problem, and none of the update method needs: cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

Answer (score 0):

It'll not work the way you do.

You should implement delegate method of UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // calculate size of image and return its height here
}
```